# How do I run gulp on Heroku?

Tags: node.js, bash, heroku, gulp

I deployed to Heroku a NodeJS app that uses `gulp`, but it won't work on Heroku.

Here's `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "app-name",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "previewUrl": "http://blahblah.com",
  "publishUrl": "gs://blahblah.com",
  "description": "",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git://github.com/github_username/git_repo.git"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "browser-sync": "*",
    "browserify": "*",
    "gulp": "*",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "*",
    "gulp-changed": "*",
    "gulp-filesize": "*",
    "gulp-imagemin": "*",
    "gulp-minify-css": "*",
    "gulp-notify": "*",
    "gulp-rev-all": "*",
    "gulp-sass": "*",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "*",
    "gulp-uglify": "*",
    "gulp-util": "*",
    "lodash": "*",
    "pretty-hrtime": "*",
    "require-dir": "*",
    "velocity-animate": "^1.2.2",
    "vinyl-source-stream": "*",
    "watchify": "*"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "underscore": "~1.7.0",
    "jquery": "~2.1.0",
    "keen-js": "~3.2.4",
    "superagent": "~1.2.0"
  }
}
```

Here's `gulpfile.js`:

```
var requireDir = require('require-dir');

// Require all tasks in gulp/tasks, including subfolders
requireDir('./gulp/tasks', { recurse: true });
```

Here's `Procfile`:

```
`web: gulp`
```

When I deploy to Heroku and go to the site on which the app is hosted, I get an "Application failed" error. When I check my Heroku logs, here's what I see:

```
2016-10-27T22:20:10.439111+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gulp`
2016-10-27T22:20:12.282952+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: gulp: command not found
2016-10-27T22:20:12.376610+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2016-10-27T22:20:12.371981+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-10-27T22:20:12.373134+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2016-10-27T22:20:14.527034+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gulp`
```

Why does the app do this?

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but I think it's due to the path to `gulp` in your Procfile.

`web: gulp` implies that you have `gulp` globally installed on the remote machine when in fact each Heroku build starts with a fresh dyno (ie. no assumptions are made as to the purpose of the dyno hence there are few, if any, preinstalled modules beyond the basics). In short, it cannot find `gulp` as a globally installed module.

Try updating your Procfile to use the locally installed gulp module: `web: ./node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp`.

Source: [Deploying to Heroku using Gulp, Node, and Git](https://www.sitepoint.com/deploying-heroku-using-gulp-node-git/)